# Docker compose - Run command while container is stopping gracefully

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, yaml

I would like to run a cleanup command before the container is completely stopped.

In my case deleting a pid file created by a service which causes issues upon next start if it's still there. Of course I could delete if it exists upon start. But I'm curious if I missed something in the docs.

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: ./
    command: bash -c "cd /myapp/ && ./example.sh"
```

Assume `example.sh` creates files and throws an error upon the next run if those files are still there. So something like the following would be cool

```
version: '3'
services:
  server:
    build: ./
    command: bash -c "cd /myapp/ && ./example.sh"
    onstop: bash -c "cd /myapp && rm exampleFile.txt"
```

I would expect that the `onstop` command is executed during the `stop_grace_period` after the container received the `stop_signal`.

Comment: Is `/myapp` a mounted volume? If it's not mounted, launching `docker-compose run --rm` removes container after run, so, you'll have all generated data cleaned after image building. If `/myapp` is a mounted volume, I'm afraid you have to clean `myapp` from the same place (host) where you invoked `docker-compose run`.

Comment: Yes, it's a mounted volume

Comment: In that case, control of exampleFile.txt existence should be outside, in `docker-compose run` launcher. If despite of that you still want to delete exampleFile.txt only when it fails you'll have to add this procedure to `example.sh`, because there's no `onstop` possibility in `docker-compose` file (at least in this version 1.21 docker-compose and 3.6 docker compose file). I.e, I'll add `rm exampleFile.txt` in some part inside `example.sh` because the volumes are used to have persistent data, not volatile when container exits.